# Pimoroni scrollphat import error

Tags: python, i2c, retropie

I am getting an error for both python3 and python2 with raspberry pi 0 and 3

I have tried installing from the git repo and enabled i2c.

i2c doesnt put out anything that is out of the ordinary

I am on retropie. I have tried it on multiple versions of retropie.

the one liner bash script doesnt work. I tried that first.

I am trying to use a scrollphat.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-graph.py", line 5, in <module>
    import scrollphat
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scrollphat/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    controller = IS31FL3730(smbus, font)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scrollphat/IS31FL3730.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.set_mode(self.i2cConstants.MODE_5X11)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scrollphat/IS31FL3730.py", line 62, in set_mode
    self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.i2cConstants.I2C_ADDR, self.i2cConstants.CMD_SET_MODE, [self.i2cConstants.MODE_5X11])
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Comment: Sounds like you've either not got I2C turned on, or the scrollpHAT isn't being detected.

Comment: @recantha it uses these two pins: https://pinout.xyz/pinout/scroll_phat# plugging in a different SD card allows the example scripts to run. What else could cause the scrollpHAT not to be detected?

Comment: Well, faulty hardware could cause it. Try opening a command prompt and typing: i2cdetect -y 1

Comment: @recantha i2cdetect -y 1 shows nothing of value. meaning it shows the hardware working. Switching out the SD card causes the scrollphat to work fine

Comment: When you say 'nothing of value' what do you mean? You should get a grid of dashes with at least one number in the grid somewhere. I'm trying to work out whether I2C is actually enabled or not.

Comment: @recantha ahh. I2C returns all dashes and no numbers. So its possible that even though I enabled I2C in raspi-config that its still not enabled?

Comment: Ah. In that case, you *have* enabled I2C otherwise i2cdetect would fail completely. Looks to me like I2C isn't picking up the ScrollpHAT. Looks like a duff board. I would return it and get a replacement.